# How to make Blood (or liquid) spray effect with CAEmitterLayer

Tags: ios, objective-c, xamarin.ios, caemitterlayer

I'm trying to make blood/liquid spray animation using CAEmitterLayer.  Does anyone know of any good techniques in doing so?  Or can anyone point me to any examples?  I'm trying to either make it spray out in a mist or flow out in a liquid.  I will ultimately be using a top down perspective, so I'll make it spray outward rather than falling down the screen appearing to be effected by gravity.

Comment: http://weblog.invasivecode.com/post/45058779586/caemitterlayer-and-the-ios-particle-system-lets

Comment: I did try to modify that into a more liquid form.  It didn't look very liquidy :\  It looked more like blood droplets.  Any ideas on techniques to make that look more like blood spray?